# nightwatch - still can't switch to the other window

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

The example from github doesn't work for me.

https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/369

This is my code.

```
When('I open a new browser window', () => {
    var host = 'http://www.google.com';
    client
        .windowHandle(function(wh){console.log(wh.value)})
        .url(host)
        .waitForElementVisible('#hplogo', 1000)
        .execute(function(newWindow){
            window.open('http://www.twitter.com', null, "height=1024,width=768");
        }, [host])
        .assert.urlContains('google')
        .window_handles(function(result) {
            var temp = result.value[1];
            this.switchWindow(temp);
        })
        .windowHandle(function(wh){console.log(wh.value)})
        .assert.urlContains('twitter')
        .end();
});
```

Both console.log before and after `.switchWindow` print out the same string.

Does anyone have any ideas please...?

**EDIT**

I've changed the code a bit taking into account what *pcalkins* said.

This is the code now:

```
When('I open a new browser window', () => {
    var host = 'http://www.google.com';
    client
        .windowHandle(function(wh){console.log("\nBEFORE: " + wh.value)})
        .url(host)
        .waitForElementVisible('#hplogo', 1000)
        .execute(function(newWindow){
            window.open('http://www.twitter.com', null, "height=1024,width=768");
        }, [host])
        .pause(3000)
        .window_handles(function(result) {
            console.log("\n\nHANDLE: " + result.value + "\n");
            var temp = result.value[0];
            this.switchWindow(temp);
            console.log("\n\ntemp0: " + temp + "\n");
            temp = result.value[1];
            this.switchWindow(temp);
            console.log("\n\ntemp1: " + temp + "\n");
        })
        .pause(2000);
});
```

When run, this is the result:

[image]

BEFORE is the handle for the original window.

HANDLE is both windows.

temp0 and temp1 are the two different windows in sequence. Clearly temp1 is the window I want, and yet the final `this.switchWindow` is not doing its job.

AFTER is the current window handle at the next test step.

Comment: the order of the window handles array is not guaranteed.  (it'll vary by driver/browser) Check current handle by using getCurrentWindowHandle method of driver.  The new window will be the handle in the getWindowHandles array that is not that one.

Comment: I've edited my question with new code. Why does it still not work?

Comment: Interesting, even if you put a random string in switchWindow, no error is thrown. It's like it completely ignores switchWindow.